# ¿como puedo escribir un algoritmo que me pida un numero entero y lo pase a romano de 0 a 1000 en Pseint?

Tags: algoritmos

pedir un numero en pseint y darlo en romano del 0 a 1.000 o 10.000 he tratado de buscar una solucion y no logro encontrar una que yo entienda cada paso por que tambien tengo una solucion pero es la mas inadecuada que es poner la condicional si num = 1 entonces escribir " el numero es "I" y asi sucesivamente pero creo y se que no es la manera mas adecuada mnuchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Publica tu código y tendrás respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no conozco el lenguaje Pseint, puedo darte una idea de un algoritmo que tú podrías intentar convertir a ese lenguaje (y si no lo consigues puedes preguntar de nuevo con una duda ya más concreta).

El algoritmo sería así: tendrías pre-almacenados en una tabla los números "redondos", que se escriben directamente con una letra o dos, junto con su representación en números romanos. La lista iría ordenada de mayor a menor. Por tanto contendría elementos como (1000,  "M"), (900, "CM"), (500 "D"), (400, "CD"), (100,  "C"), (90,  "XC"), (50, "L"), (40, "XL"), (10, "X"), (9, "IX"), (5, "V"), (4, "IV") y finalmente (1, "I").

Tenemos por otro lado un número dado `n` que hay que convertir en número romano.

1. Divides `n` entre el primer número de la lista (1000) y te quedas con su cociente y con su resto.
2. Imprimes tantas veces el primer símbolo de la lista ("M") como te haya salido en el cociente.
3. Con el resto aplicas el mismo método, pero yendo al segundo elemento de la lista, etc.

Naturalmente lo anterior puede ir en un bucle, y en cada iteración del bucle avanzas al siguiente elemento de la lista a la vez que haces `n` igual al resto de la iteración anterior.

Veamos un ejemplo. El número `n` es el 2548. Comenzamos por el primer elemento de la lista que vale 1000 y se representa por "M".

1. 2548 entre 1000 da de cociente 2 y de resto 548.
2. Imprimimos por tanto 2 veces "M"
3. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (900, representado "CM") siendo el nuevo `n` 548
4. 548 entre 900 da de cociente cero y resto 548
5. Imprimimos 0 veces  "CM"
6. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (500, "D") siendo `n` todavía 548
7. 548 entre 500 da de cociente 1 y de resto 48
8. Imprimimos 1 vez "D"
9. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (100, "C") siendo `n` ahora 48
10. 48 entre 100 sale 0, así que no se imprime ninguna "C", y `n` sigue siendo 48.
11. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (90, "XC") con `n=48`
12. 48 entre 90 sale de nuevo 0, así que no se imprime ninguna "XC" y `n` sigue siendo 48.
13. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (50, "L") con `n=48`
14. 48 entre 50 sale de nuevo 0, así que no se imprime ninguna "L" y `n` sigue siendo 48.
15. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (40, "XL"), con `n=48`
16. 48 entre 40 sale cociente 1 y resto 8.
17. Imprimimos por tanto 1 vez "XL"
18. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (10, "X") con `n=8`
19. 8 entre 10 tiene cociente 0 por lo que no se imprime "X" y `n` sigue siendo 8
20. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (9, "IX") con `n=8`
21. 8 entre 9 sale 0, así que no se imprime "IX" y `n` sigue siendo 8
22. Avanzamos al siguiente elemento de la lista (5, "V") con `n=8`
23. 8 entre 5 sale 1 y resto 3.
24. Se imprime 1 vez "V"
25. Se avanza al siguiente elemento de la lista (4, "IV") con `n=3`
26. 3 entre 4 es cero, no se imprime "IV"
27. Se avanza al siguiente elemento de la lista (1, "I") con `n=3`
28. 3 entre 1 es 3 y resto cero
29. Se imprime por tanto 3 veces "I"
30. Ya que el resto es cero, hemos terminado.

Al final habrás impreso "MMDXLVIII" que es la respuesta correcta.

Todo lo anterior es la ejecución "desenrollada", pero a la hora de implementarlo se haría en un bucle. El pseudo-código sería algo como:

```
se tiene una lista de parejas (valor, letra)
se tiene el numero n a convertir

mientras n sea distinto de 0:
  tomar siguiente pareja (valor, letra)
  c = n / valor   (división entera, deja solo el cociente)
  r = n % valor   (operación módulo, calcula el resto)
  imprimir c veces la letra
  n = r
```

Comment: Esto es pseint http://pseint.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=documentacion.php